# Complete newbie excited about Python. How hard would this app be to build?

Tags: python

I have been wanting to get into Python for a while now and have accumulated quite a few links to tutorials, books, getting started guides and the like. I have done a little programming in PERL and PHP, but mostly just basic stuff.

I'd like to be able to set expectations for myself, so based on the following requirements how long do you think it will take to get this app up and running?

Online Collection DB

- Users can create accounts that are authenticated through token sent via e-mail
- Once logged in, users can add items to pre-created collections (like "DVD" or "Software")
- Each collection has it's own template with attributes (ie: DVD has Name, Year, Studio, Rating, Comments, etc)
- Users can list all items in collections (all DVDs, all Software), sort by various attributes

Also: Yes I know there are lots of online tools like this, but I want to build it on my own with Python

Comment: It would take an experienced python programmer an afternoon to set up using a framework like django. You are not an experienced python progrmmer and so presumably don't know django or pylons either. So you have a language and a framework standing between you and your goal. Don't worry about how long it takes. That being said, I voted to close this as not a real question. Don't take it personally and please feel free to ask _technical_ questions with _technical_ answers as you progress.

Comment: forget python -- crippled lambdas, everything is a symbol table hack

Comment: @banister -- a symbol table hack that *works*.  Which of the implementation hacks used in other languages would be more appealing to you?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're already familiar with another programming language:

- Time to learn python basics: 1 week.
- Total time to figure out email module: 2 days.
- Total time to figure out httplib module: 1 days.
- Total time to figure out creating database: 3 days.
- Total time to learn about SQL: 2 weeks.
- Total time to figure out that you probably don't need SQL: 1 week.
- Total time writing the rest of the logic in python: 1 week.

Probably...

Comment: coding in python: priceless ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't write everything from the ground up and reuse basic components, this shouldn't be too hard. Probably the most difficult aspect will be authentication, because that requires domain specific knowledge and is hard to get right in any language. I would suggest starting with the basic functionality, even maybe learn how to get it up and running on App Engine, and then once you have the basic functionality, then you can deal with the business of authentication and users.